# Django Date unconverted data remains

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting this error Unconverted data remains.

**This is my real code ... but before this I start off with a range.**

```
Range = '2017-05-14 to 2017-05-18'
```

I then split this range :

```
Rangesplit = Range.split('to')
FirstDate = Rangesplit[0]
SecDate = Rangesplit[1]
```

The date format is

FirstDate = 2017-05-14

SecDate = 2017-05-18

**The code that I have tried , producing uncoverted data remains error
`datetime.datetime.strptime(FirstDate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()`**

What I want to do is get the difference between the 2 dates and convert the 2 dates so they can be stored in a Datefield .

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to show the code that is producing that error.

Comment: Added the code above.

Comment: This still isn't your real code. Even assuming that FirstDate is actually a string rather than an integer as you have posted, it wouldn't give the error you claim.

Comment: That is my real code , but Ive added code that appears before these lines to make it more clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

**I seem to have figured it out...**

Basically whats happening is -
 `Range.split('to')` actually leaves a space on either side of the **to**  therefore , the first date has a space at the end and the 2nd date has a space at the start which is why i am thrown this error.

Simply changing `Range.split('to`) into `Range.split(' to ')` removes the error.